# Issue in inserting data using PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

My code is working fine, but the problem is I can't insert data with same userid. Like only I can add only row with userid same in row - how can I insert data with same rows?

I can't add same thing in next rows like userid = 1 email= test@test.com message=hello.

Like when I send from userid 1 message is = hello and email = hassan@test.com, but when I send it again with different message its not inserting into database and sending previous message.

```
 <?php

//mysqli connectivity, select database
$connect= new mysqli("localhost","root","","demo") or die("ERROR:could not connect to the database!!!");

//extract all html field
extract($_POST);
if(isset($save))
{
//store textarea values in <pre> tag
$msg="$a";

//insert values in textarea table
$query="insert into textarea values('','$e','$msg')";
$connect->query($query);
echo "Data saved";  

    $query1="select * from textarea";
    $result=$connect->query($query1);


    while($row=$result->fetch_array())
        {
            $email = $row['email'];
            $message1 =$row['message'];

        }


    $type = "xml";



    $tos = preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($email));

$id = "id";
$pass = "pass";
$lang = "English";
$mask = "VOGUE";
// Data for text message
$to = "$tos";
$message = "$message1";
// Prepare data for POST request
$data = "id=".$id."&pass=".$pass."&msg=".$message."&to=".$to."&lang=".$lang."&mask=".$mask."&type=".$type;
// Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://www.outreach.pk/api/sendsms.php/sendsms/url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); //This is the result from Outreach
curl_close($ch);
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
input,textarea{width:250px}
textarea{height:200px}
input[type=submit]{width:150px}
</style>
        <!-- 
         * @Package: Ultra Admin - Responsive Theme
         * @Subpackage: Bootstrap
         * @Version: 1.0
         * This file is part of Ultra Admin Theme.
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> Admin : Sms Send</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta content="" name="description" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />    <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">  <!-- For iPhone -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">    <!-- For iPhone 4 Retina display -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">    <!-- For iPad -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">    <!-- For iPad Retina display -->




        <!-- CORE CSS FRAMEWORK - START -->
        <link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!-- CORE CSS FRAMEWORK - END -->

        <!-- OTHER SCRIPTS INCLUDED ON THIS PAGE - START --> 
        <!-- OTHER SCRIPTS INCLUDED ON THIS PAGE - END --> 


        <!-- CORE CSS TEMPLATE - START -->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!-- CORE CSS TEMPLATE - END -->

    </head>
    <!-- END HEAD -->

    <!-- BEGIN BODY -->
    <body class=" ">
        <!-- START TOPBAR -->
        <div class='page-topbar '>
            <div class='logo-area'>

            </div>
            </div>
        <!-- END TOPBAR -->
        <!-- START CONTAINER -->
        <div class="page-container row-fluid">

            <!-- SIDEBAR - START -->
            <div class="page-sidebar ">


                <!-- MAIN MENU - START -->
                <?php include('header.php'); ?>
                <!-- MAIN MENU - END -->



                </div>
            <!--  SIDEBAR - END -->
            <!-- START CONTENT -->
            <section id="main-content" class=" ">
                <section class="wrapper" style='margin-top:60px;display:inline-block;width:100%;padding:15px 0 0 15px;'>

                    <div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
                        <div class="page-title">

                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <h1 class="title">Form Validations</h1>                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>


                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <section class="box ">
                            <header class="panel_header">
                                <h2 class="title pull-left">Message Validations</h2>

                            </header>

                                    <form method="post">
<table width="200" border="1">

  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><textarea type="text" name="e" /></textarea></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Message</td>
    <td><textarea placeholder="contents"  name="a"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Display" name="disp"/>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>


                        </section></div>











                </section>
            </section>
            <!-- END CONTENT -->
            <div class="page-chatapi hideit">

                <div class="search-bar">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="chat-wrapper">
                    <h4 class="group-head">Groups</h4>
                    <ul class="group-list list-unstyled">
                        <li class="group-row">
                            <div class="group-status available">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Work</a></h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="group-row">
                            <div class="group-status away">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Friends</a></h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>


                    <h4 class="group-head">Favourites</h4>
                    <ul class="contact-list">

                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_1' data-user-id='1'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-1.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Clarine Vassar</a></h4>
                                <span class="status available" data-status="available"> Available</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status available">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_2' data-user-id='2'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-2.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Brooks Latshaw</a></h4>
                                <span class="status away" data-status="away"> Away</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status away">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_3' data-user-id='3'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-3.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Clementina Brodeur</a></h4>
                                <span class="status busy" data-status="busy"> Busy</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status busy">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>


                    <h4 class="group-head">More Contacts</h4>
                    <ul class="contact-list">

                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_4' data-user-id='4'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-4.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Carri Busey</a></h4>
                                <span class="status offline" data-status="offline"> Offline</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status offline">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_5' data-user-id='5'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-5.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Melissa Dock</a></h4>
                                <span class="status offline" data-status="offline"> Offline</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status offline">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_6' data-user-id='6'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-1.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Verdell Rea</a></h4>
                                <span class="status available" data-status="available"> Available</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status available">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_7' data-user-id='7'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-2.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Linette Lheureux</a></h4>
                                <span class="status busy" data-status="busy"> Busy</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status busy">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_8' data-user-id='8'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-3.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Araceli Boatright</a></h4>
                                <span class="status away" data-status="away"> Away</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status away">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_9' data-user-id='9'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-4.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Clay Peskin</a></h4>
                                <span class="status busy" data-status="busy"> Busy</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status busy">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_10' data-user-id='10'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-5.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Loni Tindall</a></h4>
                                <span class="status away" data-status="away"> Away</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status away">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_11' data-user-id='11'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-1.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Tanisha Kimbro</a></h4>
                                <span class="status idle" data-status="idle"> Idle</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status idle">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="user-row" id='chat_user_12' data-user-id='12'>
                            <div class="user-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="data/profile/avatar-2.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Jovita Tisdale</a></h4>
                                <span class="status idle" data-status="idle"> Idle</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-status idle">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="chatapi-windows ">


            </div>    </div>
        <!-- END CONTAINER -->
        <!-- LOAD FILES AT PAGE END FOR FASTER LOADING -->


        <!-- CORE JS FRAMEWORK - START --> 
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="assets/plugins/viewport/viewportchecker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <!-- CORE JS FRAMEWORK - END --> 


        <!-- OTHER SCRIPTS INCLUDED ON THIS PAGE - START --> 
        <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/additional-methods.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="assets/js/form-validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- OTHER SCRIPTS INCLUDED ON THIS PAGE - END --> 


        <!-- CORE TEMPLATE JS - START --> 
        <script src="assets/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <!-- END CORE TEMPLATE JS - END --> 

        <!-- Sidebar Graph - START --> 
        <script src="assets/plugins/sparkline-chart/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/chart-sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Sidebar Graph - END --> 













        <!-- General section box modal start -->
        <div class="modal" id="section-settings" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ultraModal-Label" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog animated bounceInDown">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Section Settings</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        Body goes here...

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- modal end -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand your text, but you might have a unique key on userid in the database table. "userid 1:3, same rows"? Also see your log files.

Comment: i dont know abut this . i cant add same thing in rows like userid = 1 email= test@test.com message=hello i cant add those in new line

Comment: You Posted Whole Code. Was This Necessary ?

Comment: `userid` *should* be the primary unique key. Of course there mustn't be any duplicates. What is your intention?

Comment: `userid` column is primary-key and auto-incremented ?

Comment: userid linked with users table and its auto increasement

Comment: i am creating sms spoofing script so i used userid which user is login his id insert into database which sms he is sending but i cant use multiple userid in rows only 1 is inserting

Comment: like when i send from userid 1 message is = hello and email = hassan@test.com but when i send it again with different message its not inserting into database and sending previous message

Comment: Ok, the table name you store data in is "textarea"? userid shall be a foreign key to the user table? Why is it autoinc in textarea? You should check your table schema and might need to remove any primary or unique key from textarea except a primary key with autoinc on the id of the message entry itself. Show the create table statement please. `SHOW CREATE TABLE textarea`

Comment: CREATE TABLE `textarea` (
 `user_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `numb` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `message` (`message`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `numb` (`numb`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Remove the PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE KEYs.

Comment: how can i do it sir i am newbie :)

Comment: and from where i have to delet those primary and unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need duplicate rows, remove indexes from the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `textarea`
DROP INDEX `message`
DROP INDEX `user_id`
DROP INDEX `numb`
DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

The above is one statement.

Please also read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)